# Care to check what is wrong with my C code

Tags: c, syntax, syntax-error

I yet again face an error message from this compiler in my online class. I have no idea what this syntax error might be since I've gone trough the code several times and it's almost identical with the example code given in the chapter I'm working on. I thought fresh experienced eyes could spot what I'm missing here
 all tough it might be something completely stupid

EDIT: The error message is just syntax error
"
There is a syntax error in the source code
Check, if you have forgotten a semicolon from the end of a line.
Check the source code near {. "

EDIT2: Yeah it was the lacking ")" thanks for the quick help again!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int i ;
FILE *kirj_tied ;
char luettelo[] = "luettelo.txt";

struct henkilo 
{
    char etunimi[21];
    char sukunimi[21];
    char numero[21];
};

struct henkilo henkilo_lista[50];

for (i=0 ; i < 50 ; i++)
{
    printf("Anna etunimi:\n");
    scanf("%s",henkilo_lista[i].etunimi);
    printf("Anna sukunimi:\n");
    scanf("%s",henkilo_lista[i].sukunimi);
    printf("Anna puhelinnumero:\n");
    scanf("%s",henkilo_lista[i].numero);
}

if ((kirj_tied = fopen(luettelo,"w") == NULL)
    {
        printf("Virhe tiedoston avaamisessa.");
        return 0 ;
    }
else
    {
        for(i=0 ; i<50 ; i++)
        {
            fprintf(kirj_tied,"%s %s %s\n", henkilo_lista[i].etunimi,henkilo_lista[i].sukunimi,henkilo_lista[i].numero);
        }
    }

    fclose(kirj_tied);
    printf("Tietojen tallennus onnistui.");
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Please add an error message.

Comment: "I yet again face a error message from this compiler in my online class." And you thought it wouldn't be necessary to include it in the question?

Comment: Wasn't there some sort of error message?  It'd help if you included that...

Comment: You mean other than the unmatched parentheses in the `fopen()` statement?

Comment: Would help if you posted the error message, but it's most likely this line: `if ((kirj_tied = fopen(luettelo,"w") == NULL)`, due to its extra `(` character.

Comment: Missing parenthesis on your `fopen()` line.

Comment: Ha, scooped you all by about 15 seconds :-)

Comment: @alexis: Noooooooo!

Comment: Actually it lacked an ")" but now there's something else wrong, lets see if I'm smart enough to figure out what.

EDIT: Ty, I just went "too far" in the current task.

Comment: For future reference, compilation errors can be found be either an IDE or some online tool, for example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
if ((kirj_tied = fopen(luettelo,"w") == NULL)
```

is missing a parenthesis perhaps? Should be:

```
if ((kirj_tied = fopen(luettelo,"w")) == NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a right paren (`)`) on the line with the `if`-statement.

It should read

```
if ((kirj_tied = fopen(luettelo, "w")) == NULL) {
                                     ^ that one
```

Running a code indenter over the code would have flagged this.  Most compilers would have given you a more helpful error message.

The Clang compiler, for example, says

```
prog.c:28:5: error: expected ')'
    {
    ^
prog.c:27:4: note: to match this '('
if ((kirj_tied = fopen(luettelo,"w") == NULL)
   ^
```